# how to make my desktop application to web app application in java

Tags: java

I have designed a GUI connect to DB button using Swing in java now i want to make it webapp application I need to host it on my website. Do i need to replace all my coding as swing is only for desktop application. Or is there any other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will partly depend on how well you've structured your application. If there's no layering involved - if the GUI classes connect directly to the database, for example, then yes, you'll need to rewrite the whole thing.

If, however, you already have a separate data access layer, business logic layer and presentation layer, then you may only need to completely rewrite the presentation layer - while checking the other layers for things like concurrency safety.

The stateless nature of web applications - aside from session-based state - may mean you need to redesign the application significantly, of course. This may in turn mean that your existing "backend" layers aren't quite appropriate. While the *theory* is that they'd be presentation-layer-neutral, in my experience it would be quite unusual to manage to write an app targeting a single UI technology without some of the usage assumptions leaking through into underlying layers.

Comment: * Take a bow * Brilliant answering!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm getting it correctly, you need to reuse a database connection code. In that case:

You need to remove only the code that references Swing components. The ones that start with `J`. More accurately - the ones that are in package `javax.swing` or `java.awt`. The rest of the code can stay.

However, if your database connectivity code is too coupled to the GUI code, you'd better start that from scratch and just copy-paste of the parts in your Swings application.

In case you have a big Swing application, then you *might* want to use an automatic converter to web (ajax) application instead.

One such solution is [**AjaxSwing**](http://www.creamtec.com/products/ajaxswing/). There may exist others as well.

Answer (score 1):

Check GWT, its a great framework that allows you to code in java...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [AjaxSwing](http://www.creamtec.com/products/ajaxswing/solutions/migrate_swing_to_html.html). It is a web deployment platform for Java Swing applications. It allows companies that built Java desktop applications to run them as web applications. Because it produces pure HTML/JavaScript you can also run Swing application on [iPhone, iPad and Android phones](http://www.creamtec.com/products/ajaxswing/solutions/java_swing_ui_on_ipad.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to replace all the GUI layer with web-app stuff (jsps, controllers etc). It should be relatively easy if you kept the business layer separated from the GUI layer. I suggest taking a look at Spring Framework, it is very useful for developing web apps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a Swing like application on the web, you can use an [Applet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Applet).

Answer (score 0):

You can turn your swing application into an applet, then it will run in a web browser, provided a JRE is installed on the client machine.

Comment: If it's connecting directly to the database, that would mean making the database publicly accessible too. That doesn't sound like a great idea to me.

Comment: For remote databases, I agree. However, we don't know if he meant a remote database since the question contains no information about this. If it is a in-memory or client side database, the situation is different and I don't see this problem then.

Answer (score 0):

What can be reused depends upon your architecture. Look at [Wicket](http://wicket.apache.org/), which offers a programming model very similar to Swing. That would not avoid rewriting of the GUI but makes the "mental mapping" easy.